# Failed to load rewarded video ads error code 3

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to display rewarded video ads using Admob but i keep getting the error : Failed to load rewarded ads error code 3. I tried my own ad unit id and also google test unit id. But receiving the same error. Banner and Interstitial ads are working fine.

I have not published the app yet. So I am trying to use it as test device. Facing the problem in Android.

Please help. any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im having the same problem. And all my Ads(Banner, Interstitial & RewardVideo) worked fine in testing. In live app, only reward video fails with error 3. Is it that we just need to wait for them(Reward Videos) to be activated and sent to our app?

Comment: Found any solution?